# Optimization of a MySQL Query with Simple Join across 3 tables

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have the following Database tables:

```
users
user_id (INT) (PRIMARY), is_cool (TINY) (1 or 0)

INDEX ON is_cool

activity 
activity_id (INT) (PRIMARY), user_id (INT), item_id (INT), created_at (DATETIME)

INDEX on item_id
INDEX on user_id
INDEX on created_at

items
item_id (INT) (PRIMARY), item_name VARCHAR(255), item_parent_id INT()

INDEX ON item_parent_id
```

I'm trying to do simple join on the these tabels, and I'm getting long query times (> 2sec) by query is below:

```
SELECT i.item_name, a.activity_id, a.user_id, a.created_at
FROM activity as a
INNER JOIN item as i on a.item_id = i.item_id
INNER JOIN users as u on u.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE i.item_parent_id = 1 and u.is_cool = 1
ORDER by a.created_at DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Any suggestions on how to improve this? It seems to be hanging due the large nature of the DB. For smaller records it works fine, but for records with 100k records - its taking a long time process.

Comment: You might want to provide your table schema. Are your column datatypes identical? What datatypes are you using for your columns? It's likely that your problems lie here.

Comment: Just added that in the post. All are INT, DATETIME, VARCHAR

Comment: INDEX on created_at is desc?  `index_col_name : col_name [( length )] [ASC | DESC] `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution plan here depends on the data distribution in your db, but MySQL will hardly pick the right index here anyway.

**Problem**

You basicaly want to iterate through all activities sorted by created_at which conform to conditions in other tables. Most probably, MySQL will treat the condition `i.item_parent_id = 1` more selective and start joining from the `item` table. That is, sorting is going to be on a field in a joined table which results in filesorts and bad performance if the join produces most of the rows from activities table. It would be better if you showed us the result of the `EXPLAIN`.

**Solution**

If the result of `activity JOIN item` produces few rows (say, less than 1000), I would just create the following indexes: the one you already have on `item_parent_id`, a composite index on `activity` `(item_id, created_at)`, and `(user_id, is_cool)` on users.

If the result of `activity JOIN item` produces many rows (more probable), I would create `(item_id, created_at)` on `activity`, `(item_id, item_parent_id)` on `item`, `(user_id, is_cool)` on `users`, and add a STRAIGHT_JOIN option to the query:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN i.item_name, a.activity_id, a.user_id, a.created_at
FROM activity as a
INNER JOIN item as i on a.item_id = i.item_id
INNER JOIN users as u on u.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE i.item_parent_id = 1 and u.is_cool = 1
ORDER by a.created_at DESC
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

Comment: The problem here is that the rows between activity and item can range from being very large or very small. Will this work for both cases?

Comment: @gregavola, try the second aproach, this should cover more cases.

Comment: This worked perfect. Bravo! The STRAIGHT_JOIN worked right out of the box and didn't require any extra indexes. However - I have a new problem. If i run the same query - but instead of showing data, i'm counting it (SELECT count(a.activity_id)) then it stalls and take longer. Why would this work here, but not when I want to count?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I can't really test this without the actual database to be sure, but i'd try moving as many as possible of the where clauses to the appropriate join clauses.

something like this may help:

```
SELECT 
      i.item_name
    , a.activity_id
    , a.user_id
    , a.created_at
FROM activity as a
INNER JOIN item as i 
    ON  a.item_id = i.item_id
    AND i.item_parent_id = 1
INNER JOIN users as u 
    ON u.user_id = a.user_id 
    AND u.is_cool = 1
ORDER by a.created_at DESC
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

Comment: The query is actually equivalent to the one of the OP. If you look at the results of the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` you will see that MYSQL rewrites inner JOINS exactly the opposite: all conditions go the the WHERE clause =)

Comment: @newtover: really? I didn't knew that. Seems like a _really_ stupid way to optimize too!

Comment: @Kris: No idea how MySQL optimizer works but I'm sure this would be only the first step of optimizing.

Comment: @ypercube: And then come proper column types with indexes (and foreign keys if you're on InnoDB). It does seem like we forgot about normalization, but I don't know what his schema models etc.)

Comment: @Kris: My comment was only about the optimizer. Rewriting queries in different ways is (pretty sure) a task that most optimizers can (or should) do. That doesn't mean that the finally chosen execution plan will refelect the rewritting. Rewriting all conditions from `INNER ` joins to `WHERE` does **not mean** that the plan will be: do a `CROSS JOIN` of all tables, then apply the `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: @ypercube: Thanks for making me laugh. I agree.